# Change Color for 3D Polygon with Nutiteq 3D SDK

Tags: android, nutiteq

I am trying to load the 3D polygons on the map. I am able to successfully load the 3d polygon but i am not able to define the color for polygon.

```
     Polygon3DStyleBuilder polygon3DStyleBuilder = new Polygon3DStyleBuilder();
     polygon3DStyleBuilder.setColor(new Color(0xFF3333FF));
     Polygon3D polygon3D = new Polygon3D(polygon3DPoses, polygon3DHoles, polygon3DStyleBuilder.buildStyle(), 150);
   polygon3D.setMetaDataElement("ClickText", "3D Polygon");
  vectorDataSource.add(polygon3D);
```

As seen in the screen the side wall is in lighter color compared to the top one. Is there a way i can define different color for side walls and the top or the same color on both side?

[image]

Comment: The color difference comes from lightning definition, without it you would not see 3D effect for the polygon. Currently you cannot set own different color (e.g. green) to the sides.

Comment: @JaakL OK. Can I have the darker shade on side and lighter on top?

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting the main light attributes as follows:

```
mapView.getOptions().setMainLight(new Color(1,1,1,1), new MapVec(0, 0, -1))
```

This will change the light direction to be from straight up. The top will be lighter and sides darken, but all sides will have the same color.

Comment: this changes side and top to same color and all coming up in dark